# R: create an array of expressions to pass to function

Tags: r

I am using the **glm** function, which accepts an argument called **family** as below:

```
glm(..., family = gaussian("identity"))
```

I would like to create an array of possible options for **family** and loop through them. My initial thought was to use **quote**, like this:

```
fam.array <- c( quote(gaussian("identity")), quote(gaussian("inverse"),
             quote(gaussian("log")))

for(i in 1:3) glm(..., family = fam.array[i])
```

When I examine **fam.array[1]**, I get **gaussian("identity")** as expected. Nevertheless, **glm** doesn't like the expression. What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: What about if you create a list of family objects and pass that along? `list(gaussian("identity"), binomial(link = "logit"))`

Answer (score 1):

Create a list instead:

```
fam.list <- list(gaussian("identity"), gaussian("inverse"), gaussian("log"))
```

or

```
fam.list <- lapply(c("identity", "inverse", "log"), gaussian)
```

and then:

```
lapply(fam.list, glm, formula = demand ~ Time, data = BOD)
```